# Xamarin Forms config file

Tags: xamarin, configuration, configuration-files

I am currently working on a xamarin app, and I am having issues with creating a config file that contains one default setting for different environments such as Android and UWP. Anyone know a good solution for this?

Comment: google "xamarin config" - there are numerous excellent hits on doing this

Comment: @Jason in my application I have a class called constants.cs and in it I have settings like:         public static string WebViewPageHybridWebViewName => "WebView"; AND         public static string SettingsPageChangePassWordText => "New password"; I wonder how I can put these settings in a config file? Or is it even possible to put them in a config file? I dont really understand how to use config..

Comment: @Jason Was I clear?

Comment: @Dell97 If you want to store default setting value, I suggest you can use [Xamarin.Essentials: Preferences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/preferences?tabs=android)

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT how can I do that with a config file?

Comment: @Dell97 I find one sample about creating config file and read it by Newtonsoft.Json, you can take a look:[XamarinConfig](https://github.com/johnthiriet/XamarinConfig)

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT Thanx!